# mvim (MacVim 7.4) opening new windows rather than tabs (Mac OS X 10.8.5)

Tags: macos, terminal, macvim

I am using the above and editing new files using `mvim <filename>`. The first time after I installed mvim in the /usr/local/bin directory it seemed to open files in new tabs by default, this behaviour has now stopped.

### I would like to know the .vimrc setting to turn it back on or mvim switch that I should use to open files so that they are tabbed instead of opened as new windows.

The .vimrc I am using currently is:

```
set number
set ruler
"folding settings
set foldmethod=indent   "fold based on indent
set foldnestmax=20      "deepest fold is 10 levels
set nofoldenable        "dont fold by default
set foldlevel=31        "this is just what i use
set ignorecase
```

I don't think any of the above should change the behaviour of mvim and the way it opens new files.

I've already read:
[MacVim -- switch to tab where file is opened if trying to open an already-opened file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53732/10733); and
[Use MacVim as standard Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14202/10733); and I am also in the middle of reading :help mvim

I am sure I have read the answer somewhere, however I cannot remember where and now cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### use the `--remote-tab` command line switch, as in:

```
mvim --remote-tab foobar.txt
```

The answer was obtained by reading `help:mvim` it is located in section 14 of the help file titled **macvim-hints**.

Extracted here is the relevant section of the MacVim 7.4 help file:

> Scenario:
>
> ~ You want to open a file in a tab in an already opened
>    window, but typing "mvim filename" in Terminal opens it up in a
>    separate window.
>
> Solution:
>
> ~ Use the |--remote-tab| switch.  If you
>    have several windows open you might have to specify which window you
>    want the file to open in by using the |--servername| switch.  The
>    title of a window usually ends in something like "VIM" or "VIM3" ---
>    this is the server name of that window.  So to open a file named
>    "foobar.txt" in a window whose title ends in "VIM3" you would type
>    (the order of the arguments matters):
>
> `mvim --servername VIM3 --remote-tab foobar.txt`
>
> For more information, consult the |client-server| manual page.